# Action called twice

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a `@Html.Action()` in my layout, and putting a breakpoint in the controller action behind this shows it is being called twice (one seems to be as part of the overall controller action returning my main `View` and the second seems to be on the `@Renderbody()` call).

This results in my partial view being returned from the action (depending on the user role) being shown twice, once in the right place in the layout (where the `@Html.Action()` call is and once within the rest of the page, just before where next `@Html.Action()` call is inside the main page being shown in the layout.

I assume it has something to do with `@Renderbody()` displaying all partial views returned from the controller but I have no idea.

Any pointers on if this is true, and if so how can I show my menu without using an action?

Comment: hi, i'm using @Html.Action on layout (forexample language, authorize user settings) and never call two times..I am wondering how, could you please paste piece of code about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar situation where I was calling an `ActionResult` using `@Html.Action` in order to render a partial view (after processing some data), however it kept repeating the layout twice. To fix it I had to change the `ActionResult` to a `PartialViewResult`, even though both were returning a partial view, the former seemed to treat it as if it were returning a view anyway...